Yandex авторизация в next-auth с адаптером (invalid_grant)
Стек: Next 14, next-auth 4, yandex provider, hasura adaptor.
Без провайдера авторизация проходит успешно. Когда подключаю адаптер (использую стратегию jwt) падает ошибка invalid_grant (code has expired). Хотя юзер записан в базу со всеми данными. И ему приходится нажимать авторизацию снова.
Причина в том, что next-auth отправляет два запроса на token endpoint. Так как grant код одноразовый, то я получается такая ошибка. Я думаю так.
С гугл и гитхаб такого нет.
Redirect в яндекс oauth консоли: http: localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/yandex.
Проверял на vercel. Та  же ошибка.
Если в гугл хроме включить slow 3g ошибка пропадает.
Пытался в middleware ставить задержку на запросы в api/auth/callback/yandex. Локально работает. Но у меня деплой на vercel. А там не работает. Пробовал разные интервалы.
Сталкивался ли кто-то? Как лечили? Есть ли идеи как обойти? Ошибка думаю со стороны next-auth.
На их гите оставил issue. Пока ноль реакции.
